# Single tab in navigation bar displaying lower than other tabs

Tags: html, css

I am working on a draft for a portfolio website. Still a beginner and this site will probably end up changing quite a bit as I progress. I noticed that I can't seem to get my nav bar to align properly, the "portfolio" tab rests below the other tabs and nothin in my CSS should account for this, am I missing something?
Here's the link to live site:
http://artuciidesigns.epizy.com/index.html?i=3
Here is my code:

```css
/* CSS Document */
body {background-color: whitesmoke;}





/* Header */
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #61d1e2; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background-image: linear-gradient(#e7bddc, #61d1e2);
}
.header_content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #61d1e2; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background-image: linear-gradient(#e7bddc, #61d1e2);
}

.logo_container {
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    float: left;
    border: none;
}
.logo {
    
    max-height: 50px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
/* Navigation */

body {
  margin: 0;
  
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #61d1e2; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background-image: linear-gradient(#e7bddc, #61d1e2);
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #067393;
  font-family: Kapelka New;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  
  color: #bc0456;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #bc0456;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
    
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #067393;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: Kapelka New;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightblue;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: #067393;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #61d1e2; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background-image: linear-gradient(#e7bddc, #61d1e2);
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #067393;
  font-family: Kapelka New;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #;
  color: #bc0456;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #bc0456;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
    
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #067393;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: Kapelka New;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightblue;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: #067393;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn"><a href="portfolio2.html">Portfolio</a>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="FINAL_LOGO_PORTFOLIO copy.pdf">Logo Portfolio</a>
      <a href="Menu Designs.pdf">Menu Designs</a>
      <a href="mag1.pdf">Magazine Design 1</a>
      <a href= "mag2.pdf">Magazine Design 2</a>
    
    </div>
    </div> 
  <a href="about_Me2.html">About ME</a>
  <a href="contact2.html">Contact</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Both your button and the `a` tag within it have padding, which is causing the effect you're seeing. In addition to this, there is whitespace between the `.dropbtn` and the following `.dropdown-content` which causes and extra 5 pixels to be added to the container's height. You can eiher remove this whitespace by putting the closing `button` tag and opening `div` tag on the same line, or set the `.dropdown` classes font size to 0. Here is a corrected version of your code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #61d1e2; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background-image: linear-gradient(#e7bddc, #61d1e2);
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #067393;
  font-family: Kapelka New;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #;
  color: #bc0456;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #bc0456;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
    
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0px; /* Prevent whitespace within the div from rendering */
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #067393;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: Kapelka New;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightblue;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: #067393;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
    <body>

        <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
            <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn"><a href="portfolio2.html">Portfolio</a>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="FINAL_LOGO_PORTFOLIO copy.pdf">Logo Portfolio</a>
                <a href="Menu Designs.pdf">Menu Designs</a>
                <a href="mag1.pdf">Magazine Design 1</a>
                <a href="mag2.pdf">Magazine Design 2</a>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <a href="about_Me2.html">About ME</a>
        <a href="contact2.html">Contact</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This definitely fixed the issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're nesting `<a>` inside `<button>`, and both have their own padding, so you end up having extra space in that button element. Removing `padding` from `dropbtn` should work.

```css
/* CSS Document */
body {background-color: whitesmoke;}





/* Header */
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #61d1e2; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background-image: linear-gradient(#e7bddc, #61d1e2);
}
.header_content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #61d1e2; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background-image: linear-gradient(#e7bddc, #61d1e2);
}

.logo_container {
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    float: left;
    border: none;
}
.logo {
    
    max-height: 50px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
/* Navigation */

body {
  margin: 0;
  
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #61d1e2; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background-image: linear-gradient(#e7bddc, #61d1e2);
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #067393;
  font-family: Kapelka New;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  
  color: #bc0456;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #bc0456;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
    
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #067393;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: Kapelka New;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightblue;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: #067393;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href="css/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #61d1e2; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background-image: linear-gradient(#e7bddc, #61d1e2);
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #067393;
  font-family: Kapelka New;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #;
  color: #bc0456;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #bc0456;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
    
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #067393;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: Kapelka New;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lightblue;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: #067393;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn"><a href="portfolio2.html">Portfolio</a>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="FINAL_LOGO_PORTFOLIO copy.pdf">Logo Portfolio</a>
      <a href="Menu Designs.pdf">Menu Designs</a>
      <a href="mag1.pdf">Magazine Design 1</a>
      <a href= "mag2.pdf">Magazine Design 2</a>
    
    </div>
    </div> 
  <a href="about_Me2.html">About ME</a>
  <a href="contact2.html">Contact</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

You used a **button** element for the 'Portfolio' tab. HTML's button element has default preset styles that need to be changed.

```
button {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Add this to your stylesheet and take a look!